# Why won't my hyperlinks work in the CartoDB infowindow?

Tags: carto, infowindow

I've been setting up a map of project locations for my company, and I want the infowindow to include a link to the more detailed project description page on our website. I have checked several of the other questions related to URLs in CartoDB infowindows, but none seem to cover the same issue.

I uploaded a dataset with the URLs for our project pages in a field called "Link" and I tried using the following in the Custom HTML window (along with a thumbnail image of the project and a couple other details):

```
<p><a href="{{Link}}">more info</a></p>
```

When I check the "more info" link in the infowindow on the map, it always points back to the map itself (https://bfradkin.cartodb.com/viz/ce4b4070-87f8-11e5-b01c-0ea31932ec1d/map), not the URL stored in the Link field.

See below for a screenshot showing the map URL when I hover over the link:
[image]

I'm hoping to solve this without getting into CartoDB.js, any thoughts?

Comment: I think you're seeing links not working where the LINK field is empty - try fields that have a value in LINK and they should work (I downloaded your dataset and put it into a map of my own, and used the same method you've used - only I categorized the points by the LINK field so I could see where LINK was null, and where there was a value...)

Comment: Thanks for checking it, there are still a lot of empty link fields, but when I try the links for projects where it is populated, it gives me the same result. I also tried opening the dataset in a new map, and it didn't work for me. Did the active links work differently for you when you tried it?

Comment: They take me to the http://geoadaptive.com/projects/keysmap1/ pages, etc.

Comment: Ok, I tried the dataset again in a new map, and the links do work there, so it must be something else in the Custom HTML messing it up. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to mapBaker for confirming there was nothing wrong with my Link field. After resetting the Custom HTML and adding the href code back again, it seems to work as expected.